# websockify - send enter key through web socket to automatically get login prompt

Tags: javascript, websocket, telnet

I have a webpage with the telnet client from websockify. On page load, I automatically connect to the right host with its port. But before I get a login prompt, I have to press the enter key first.

How do I automatically send the enter key event so that the login prompt is shown upon page load?

Comment: Please provide some code snip , you have tried.

Comment: @San Nothing, really... I'm not sure where to add that line of code.

Comment: Well... please provide the page code. For example - is the `enter` event customized or does it invoke a form submission (which means imitating a POST request)?

Answer (score 0):

The `Telnet` object doesn't expose any API to send arbitrary strings. It only sends what it captures on `key_down` events.

But you can do it with some hacks, by using some exposed internal properties.

Modify the `connected` event handler in `wstelnet.html`, like so:

```
function connected() {
    $D('connectButton').disabled = false;
    $D('connectButton').value = "Disconnect";
    $D('connectButton').onclick = disconnect;

    VT100.the_vt_.key_buf_.push("\n");
    VT100.go_getch_();
}
```

Comment: This modification does send a new line, I can see the cursor moving. But this doesn't simulate an enter key event.